# SENTRY IOS SDK not sending events

Tags: ios, swift, crash, sentry

I'm using Sentry ios sdk v7.31.5

but it never sends events to sentry dashboard "issues" or maybe it's sent but never shows up in the dashboard

I tried capturing custom message

```
SentrySDK.capture(message: "TESTING SENTRY IOS")
```

but it never shows up

Answer (score 1):

You have to ensure to start the SDK before sending events. On iOS, Sentry recommends doing this in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
import Sentry // Make sure you import Sentry

// ....

func application(_ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    SentrySDK.start { options in
        options.dsn = "Your DSN"
    }

    return true
}
```

If you use SwiftUI, do it in the [App conformer's initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/app/main()):

```
import Sentry

@main
struct SwiftUIApp: App {
    init() {
        SentrySDK.start { options in
            options.dsn = "Your DSN"
    }
}
```

You can find more info here https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/apple/guides/ios/.